# knife ssh range of host names with numbers

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I can't seem to get knife ssh/search to expand a range of hostnames that differ only by number.  For example, if I have host1.example.com, host2.example.com, host3.example.com,...host50.example.com I can't get either of these two queries using knife's range to work properly, e.g.,

```
knife ssh 'name:[host1.example.com TO name:host50.example.com]'
```

or

```
knife ssh 'name:host[1 TO 50].example.com'
```

In the first case I just getting the beginning host and the end host returned.  In the latter case I get the following error message

```
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
Response: invalid search query
```

The hosts otherwise do not differ, i.e, by role nor environments, so I'm forced to use name.  And it's more than a little tedious to type something like,

```
knife ssh 'name:host1.example.com OR name:host2.example.com OR name:host3.example.com...OR name:host50.example.com
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ranges in search queries don't work in a useful way. Remember that Solr is built for text search and that we cram all attributes into a single facet. You'll have to use a mix of wild cards and local filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I've used variations of this to do my work, as oppose to doing iterative calls to knife ssh.

```
NODES=""
for i in {01..50}
do
  if [ ! -z "${NODES} ]; then
    NODES="${NODES} or name:<hostprefix>${i}"
  else
    NODES="name:<hostprefix>${i}"
  fi
done
knife ssh "${NODES} -x user -i ~/.ssh/key.pem "some command'
```